# ViewUtils provider (Angular 2 RC 4)

Tags: angular

trying to load dynamically child component in parent view:

```
this.viewAddedSubscription = viewManager.viewAdded.subscribe((view) => {
     let injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([new Provider('view', { useValue: view })]);

     this._componentResolver.resolveComponent(view.type).then(result => {
          this.child.createComponent(result, 0, injector);
     });
});
```

But always getting error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): No provider for ViewUtils!
```

Am i doing wrong something? If no, then can somebody show me how can i add provider for ViewUtils.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a child injector of the currents component injector, instead of an independent injector:

```
constructor(private injector:Injector) {}

someOtherMethod() {
  let resolvedProviders = ReflectiveInjector.resolve([new Provider('view', { useValue: view })]]);
  let child = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders(resolvedProviders, this.injector);
  ...
}
```

This way you pass an injector that has the same providers as your current component (everything provided globally by Angular) **and** overrides (if already provided by a parent) or adds your `view` provider.